# Jquery Javascript function, simple error, can't find it!

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, function

When my page loads it calls the function like below:

```
<body onLoad='changeTDNodes()'>
```

And the code it calls is below:

```
enter code here


<script src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>

function changeTDNodes() {
var threshValue = 10;
$(".threshold").each(function(elem) {
if($("b",elem).innerText > threshValue) {
elem.addClass("overThreshold");
}
});
});
```

}

I have the class setup correctly in CSS
.overThreshold {
td{font-size:72px;}
th{font-size:72px;}
}

But no classes are being changed, whats going on?

Thanks for all your help!

Below is whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'             'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
<title>Livermore Readerboard</title>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var threshValue = 10;
$(".threshold").each(function(elem) {
if($("b",elem).innerText > threshValue) {
elem.addClass("overThreshold");
}
});
});

</script>
<style type='text/css'>
#InnerRight {
width: 50% !important;
position: relative !important;
float: left !important;
}
#InnerLeft {
width: 49% !important;
position: relative !important;
float: right !important;
}
.overThreshold {
td{font-size:72px;}
th{font-size:72px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='InnerLeft'>
<table border=1 cellpading=1 cellspacing=0>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>Split/Skill</b></td>
<td align=center><B>CIQ</b></td>
<td align=center><b>EWT</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Agents Staffed</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Avail</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>LEAD_IP_REP_video</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>:00</b></td>
<td align=center><b>3</b></td>
<td align=center><b>2</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>LEAD_IP_REP_tier</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>:00</b></td>
<td align=center><b>3</b></td>
<td align=center><b>2</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>IP_REP_video</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>60</b></td>
<td align=center><b>10:12</b></td>
<td align=center><b>58</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>IP_REP_hsi</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>34</b></td>
<td align=center><b>18:15</b></td>
<td align=center><b>56</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>IP_REP_hn</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>3:48</b></td>
<td align=center><b>3</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>IP_REP_cdv</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>6</b></td>
<td align=center><b>14:53</b></td>
<td align=center><b>56</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
<td align=left><b>CommOps FieldCare</b></td>
<td align=center class='threshold'><B>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
<td align=center><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Delan, whilst I agree, that's not super helpful. @CodingIsAwesome, google "unobtrusive javascript" to understand the first part of Delan's comment.

Comment: kibibu, that's why I didn't post it as an answer, just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be far better off, if possible, using `id`s on your elements, and then using `document.getElementById()` (or, better yet, using Dojo, MooTools or JQuery to make your code simpler).

So your html looks like:

```
<td id="cell-repair-video">Repair value is <b>23</b></td>
<td id="cell-ppv">PPV value is <b>5</b></td>
```

Then your JavaScript looks like:

```
var RepairVideo_cell = document.getElementById("cell-repair-video");
var RepairVideo_value = RepairVideo_cell.getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
```

---

In JQuery (and others), you can easily use a class to determine which elements need thresholding

In this case, your html looks like:

```
<td class="threshold">Repair value is <b>23</b></td>
<td class="threshold">PPV value is <b>5</b></td>
```

And your *entire* JavaScript looks like:

```
$(function() {
  var threshValue = 10;
  $('.threshold').each(function(index) {
    var thisValue = parseFloat( $('b', this).text() );
    if(thisValue > threshValue) {
      $(this).addClass('overThreshold');
    }
  });
});
```

---

In your current example, there is an error in your CSS

To style `td` and `th` elements with a classname, go

```
td.overThreshold, th.overThreshold {
  background: #F00; /* for example */
}
```

Comment: Ok I used your script like so

<script>

$(function() {
  var threshValue = 10;
  $(".threshold").each(function(elem) {
    if($("b",elem).innerText > threshValue) {
      elem.addClass("overThreshold");
    }
  });
});

</script>

And then set <body onLoad='function()'>

However, nothing is working, and I am using 

<script src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: no need for the onLoad thing, that's what the surrounding $() does. Are you including the JQuery script first? Have you got some css for `.overThreshold`? Try adding `<style type="text/css">.overThreshold{ background: #F00; }</style>` in the head

Comment: Oh i see you've changed the question. What does your html look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to show all the code in the page. Thank you for helping me. I'm a Javascript and Jquery newb, and your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are passing through something to the `applyThresholds` function where innerHTML on `myvalue` is not valid. Does it work ok in firefox etc?

My guess would be that the crazy `document.getElementsByTagName('B')[36];` code is just returning undefined at some point. You should put some code in applyThresholds to check to see if you are getting invalid arguments through. Something like:

```
if(myvalue == null || mycell == null) {
   return;
}
```